# Help with horizontal alignment

Tags: horizontal-alignment

Can you help me move the text closer to the left like:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}

\begin{document}
\noindent
where
\begin{flalign*}
&\Delta f_{res} & - & \mbox{\emph{lock time in microseconds}}&&\\
&\mathcal{L} & - & \mbox{\emph{is the loop bandwidth in kHz, and}}&&\\
&f_{m} & - & \frac{Frequency~Tolerance}{Frequency~Jump}&&
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

Thanks,

Comment: a couple of suggestions: those elements on the right-hand side aren't negative, so you really don't want a minus sign.  also, `\text{...} is usually better than `\mbox`, and the words in the fraction aren't math variables multiplied together.  put these together, and get this for the last line: `&f{m} && \text{--- } \frac{\text{Frequency Tolerance}}{\text{Frequency Jump}}`.  (i'm not where i can experiment right now to figure out what's best to close up the space.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possibility that doesn't abuse `flalign`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\noindent
where
\[
\makebox[\displaywidth][l]{$\displaystyle
  \begin{array}{@{} l l @{}}
  \Delta f_{\mathrm{res}} & \mbox{---\quad \emph{lock time in microseconds,}} \\
  \mathcal{L}             & \mbox{---\quad \emph{loop bandwidth in \si{kHz}, and}} \\
  f_{m}                   & \mbox{---\quad}\dfrac{\text{\emph{Frequency Tolerance}}}
                                                 {\text{\emph{Frequency Jump}}.}
  \end{array}
$}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is your updated code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}

\begin{document}
\noindent
where
\begin{flalign*}
&\Delta f_{res} & \hspace{-1.6cm} - & \mbox{\emph{lock time in microseconds}}&&\\
&\mathcal{L} & \hspace{-2.1cm} - & \mbox{\emph{is the loop bandwidth in kHz, and}}&&\\
&f_{m} & \hspace{-2cm} - & \frac{Frequency~Tolerance}{Frequency~Jump}&&
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: still looks like minus signs making the right-hand sides negative.  see my comment on the question.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, I am trying to get bascially a dash `-` to distinguish the variables (on the left hand side), to its defintions (on the right hand side).  Thanks.

Comment: @Joe -- see my comment on the question.  `\text{--- }` is what you want, i think.  (that's an em-dash, longer than a minus sign, and i think that a space after it helps distinguish it from a minus, which, if in this context, would be a *unary* minus with no space.)

Answer (score 2):

What about this, it looks even better.

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}

\begin{document}
\noindent
where
    \begin{flalign*}
&\Delta f_{res} & \hspace{-1.6cm}{:~}  & \mbox{\emph{lock time in microseconds}}&&\\
&\mathcal{L} & \hspace{-2.1cm}{:~}  &  \mbox{\emph{is the loop bandwidth in kHz, and}}&&\\
&f_{m} & \hspace{-2cm}{:~}  & \frac{Frequency~Tolerance}{Frequency~Jump}&&
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please, don't add an answer that's simply a modification of your previous one; it's better to edit the other.

Comment: okay! got it...

Answer (score 2):

I would do this on the following way:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}%for show page layout

    \begin{document}
\noindent
where\\
$\begin{array}{rl}
\Delta f_{res}: & \textit{lock time in microseconds}    \\
\mathcal{L}:    & \textit{loop bandwidth in kHz, and}   \\
f_{m}:          & \dfrac{\textit{frequency tolerance}}{\textit{frequency jump}} 
\end{array}$

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Use of minis sign as separator between variables and its meaning can become ambiguous, so I recommend to use `:`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a left-aligned `tabular` environment to achieve your objective. (The line along the left-hand edge of the following screenshot is there to illustrate the edge of the textblock.)

[image]

Incidentally, I don't think it's really necessary to render the explanatory text snippets in italics. To render the material in the upright text font, simply remove the `\em` instruction in the code below, and replace `\textit` with `\textrm`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\usepackage{showframe}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$} }
\begin{document}
\noindent \dots

\noindent where\\[1ex]
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{} L @{\quad---\quad} >{\em}l}
\Delta f_{\textit{res}} & lock time in microseconds,\\
\mathcal{L}    & loop bandwidth in kHz, and\\[0.5ex]
f_{m}          & $\dfrac{\textit{Frequency Tolerance}}{\textit{Frequency Jump}}$\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```